# Getting the selected value from ReactDropdown component

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactDropdown from "react-dropdown" to create various drop downs in my app. I am having trouble trying to get the selected value from this component in my app. This is what I've tried but it gets me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDropdown from "react-dropdown";
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Checkbox from 'react-simple-checkbox';

class Reactor extends Component{
    state = {
        substrate: null,
        size: null,
        description: null
    }

    substrates = ['Potato', 'Carrots', 'Celery', 'Something'];

    handleDescription = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Description)")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value

        })
    }

    handleSizeDropdown = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Size)")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            size: e.target.value()
        })
    }

    handleSubstrateDropdown = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Substrate)")
        console.log(e.value)
        this.setState({
            substrate: e.target.value})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"card container col-12 col-lg-4 login-card mt-2 "}>
                <form>
                    <label className={"m-2"}>Select Substrate: </label>
                    <ReactDropdown options={this.substrates} onChange={this.handleSubstrateDropdown.bind(getSelection())}  /><br></br>
                     <label className={"m-2"}>Select Particulate Size: </label>
                    <ReactDropdown options={['Small','Medium', 'Large']} onChange={this.handleSizeDropdown.bind(getSelection())} /><br></br>
                    <label className={"m-2"}>Reactor Description: </label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" type={"text"} onChange={this.handleDescription} rows={"3"} /><br></br>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Reactor;
```

What can I do to access the selected value? For what I debugged with React Developer Tools is that the state variable of the ReactDropdown has a "selected" javascript objeect which has the value like so:

```
{
  "selected": {
    "label": "Select...",
    "value": ""
  },
  "isOpen": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to add `this` bindings for your event handlers in the constructor...

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            substrate: null,
            size: null,
            description: null
        }

        this.handleSubstrateDropdown = this.handleSubstrateDropdown.bind(this);
        this.handleSizeDropdown = this.handleSizeDropdown.bind(this);
        this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
    }
```

---

Also, you are not setting state correctly.  Instead use `this.state = { //stuff }`  inside of the constructor.  And use `this.setState()` 
 to modify state outside the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
        substrate: null,
        size: null,
        description: null
     }
```

---

Also, it appears you are trying to access `this.state.substrates` by just usings `substrates =  ...`   that won't work.   You need to use `this.setState()` to change the value of items in `this.state`.

```
this.setState({substrates : ['Potato', 'Carrots', 'Celery', 'Something']};
```

---

[React Documentation > Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

---

Can you try these changes...

```
import React, {
    Component
} from "react";
import ReactDropdown from "react-dropdown";
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
import Checkbox from 'react-simple-checkbox';

class Reactor extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            substrate: null,
            size: null,
            description: null
        }

        this.handleSubstrateDropdown = this.handleSubstrateDropdown.bind(this);
        this.handleSizeDropdown = this.handleSizeDropdown.bind(this);
        this.handleDescription = this.handleDescription.bind(this);
    }



    this.setState({substrates : ['Potato', 'Carrots', 'Celery', 'Something']};

    handleDescription = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Description)")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            description: e.target.value

        })
    }

    handleSizeDropdown = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Size)")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({
            size: e.target.value()
        })
    }

    handleSubstrateDropdown = (e) => {
        console.log("Worked (Substrate)")
        console.log(e.value)
        this.setState({
            substrate: e.target.value
        })
    }


    render() {
        return ( <
            div className = {
                "card container col-12 col-lg-4 login-card mt-2 "
            } >
            <
            form >
            <
            label className = {
                "m-2"
            } > Select Substrate: < /label> <
            ReactDropdown options = {
                this.substrates
            }
            onChange = {
                this.handleSubstrateDropdown.bind(getSelection())
            }
            /><br></br >
            <
            label className = {
                "m-2"
            } > Select Particulate Size: < /label> <
            ReactDropdown options = {
                ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
            }
            onChange = {
                this.handleSizeDropdown.bind(getSelection())
            }
            /><br></br >
            <
            label className = {
                "m-2"
            } > Reactor Description: < /label> <
            textarea className = "form-control"
            type = {
                "text"
            }
            onChange = {
                this.handleDescription
            }
            rows = {
                "3"
            }
            /><br></br >
            <
            /form> <
            /div>
        );
    }
}
```